# Extjs Make some cells uneditable while modifing

Tags: extjs

I am using Extjs3.2 and Row editor Plugin for Grid.I have Add,Modify and Delete Button.I have Four Cell in grid Say(id,firstname,lastname,roll no).In case of Add  all field should be editable so that he can add all four fields.But suppose if clicks one existing record and click on modify i want id field non editable.How to acheive this

Below is my code

```
var grid= new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                            store : store_surv,
                            id : "grid_surv",
                            columns : [

                    {
                        header : "Id",
                        width : 120,
                        sortable : true,
                        dataIndex : 'id',
                        renderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {

                             return  getToolTip(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store);
                            } ,
                        editor : {
                            xtype : 'textfield',
                            allowBlank : true
                        }
                    }
                    {
                        header : "First Name",
                        width : 120,
                        sortable : true,
                        dataIndex : 'fname',
                        renderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {

                             return  getToolTip(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store);
                            } ,
                        editor : {
                            xtype : 'textfield',
                            allowBlank : true
                        }
                    }

                    {
                        header : "Last Name",
                        width : 120,
                        sortable : true,
                        dataIndex : 'lname',
                        renderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {

                             return  getToolTip(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store);
                            } ,
                        editor : {
                            xtype : 'textfield',
                            allowBlank : true
                        }
                    },

                   {
                        header : "Roll No",
                        width : 120,
                        sortable : true,
                        dataIndex : 'roll',
                        renderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {

                             return  getToolTip(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store);
                            } ,
                        editor : {
                            xtype : 'textfield',
                            allowBlank : true
                        }
                    }                   ],



                            title : 'Student List',
                            height : 350,
                            width : 750,
                            frame : false
                        })
```

;

Answer (score 0):

Add an `afteredit` listener to your editor object and in that listener call the `setDisabled(true)` method on the id textfield like this:

```
var idTextField = Ext.create({
    xtype : 'textfield',
    allowBlank : true
});

var editor = new Ext.ux.grid.RowEditor({
    saveText: 'Update',
    listeners: {
        afteredit: function(){
            idTextField.setDisabled(true);
        }
    }
});
```

And modify your existing code by replacing the old textfield with the above mentioned:

```
...
{
  header : "Id",
  width : 120,
  sortable : true,
  dataIndex : 'id',
  renderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
                return  getToolTip(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store);
  },
  editor : idTextField
}
...
```

So we just changed the editor property.

Comment: @ its not working afteredit means when everything is done and we click on update button then it is clicked but i want beforeedit ,but problem is it will call on add also

Comment: Well, did you try it? On afteredit it disables your textfield, when you add a value first time and you won't be able to edit that when you wanna update in the future. And it's the same what you required.

Comment: No after edit is called when edit is done and somebody tries to save but i want it before save

Comment: If you dont fill the grid by hand, then use beforeedit, except afteredit.